# How to sort list of strings with numbers like result-01 , result-110

Tags: python

I got a lot of images/files in folder. They looks like

```
result-01  -> result-176
```

When I make a video from images I got wrong order (after result-10.png goes result-100.png instead of result-11.png). How to sort my files?

`os.listdir(path).sort()` dont works

```
for filename in os.listdir(path):
    print(filename)
```

I want to get

```
result-01.png
result-02.png
...
result-08.png
result-09.png
result-10.png
result-11.png
result-12.png
```

instead of

```
result-01.png
result-02.png
...
result-08.png
result-09.png
result-10.png
result-100.png
result-101.png
result-102.png
```

Comment: `list.sort` sorts strings. You need a function to parse the file number from its name and then you can do `.sort(key=file_number)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
names = ['result-01.png', 'result-100.png', 'result-12.png']

sorted(names, key=lambda x:int(x.split('-')[-1].split('.')[0]))
```

output:

```
['result-01.png', 'result-12.png', 'result-100.png']
```

Answer (score 1):

`list.sort` sorts strings as strings.

You need a function to parse the file number as an integer from the file name and then you can do `sort(key=parse_file_number)`

```
def parse_file_number(f):
    return int(f[len('result-'):-len('.png')])
```

And now you can do:

```
for filename os.listdir(path).sort(key=parse_file_number):
    # do something with filename
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the sorted function?

```
import os

for filename in sorted(os.listdir("C:\\")):
    print(filename)
```

Comment: sort and sorted dont help

The tips above solved the problem

Comment: Sort/Sorted are still used in the above solutions, however it sorts via a-z and not on the file number. So in the solutions above, they use 'sort' to sort the values based on the split filename (number) and not the filename as a whole.